# How does Mac OS reference relate to python usage?

Tags: python, macos, pdf

I'm trying to learn python and the way that it interacts with OS X's APIs, particularly for PDF. I have the following script, gleaned from the internet for getting the number of pages in a PDF:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from CoreGraphics import *

pdfnum=0

def pageCount(pdfPath):
    "Return the number of pages for some PDF file."

    pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider (CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename (pdfPath))
    return pdf.getNumberOfPages()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
        pdfnum=pdfnum+pageCount(filename)

print pdfnum
```

I can't find anything in Apple's reference material that corresponds with the words used here. I have no idea why we're Creating a new PDF document, when we only want to read attributes of an existing document.
The PDFDocument object has a pageCount method, but we're defining our own function with that name here, and that's not the 'getNumberOfPages' that seems to be the method mentioned in the script. I can't find that word in Apple's reference at all.

In short: I don't see how I link up the terms used in Apple's reference material with words that I might want to use in my scripts.

Comment: it's not a "new" pdf document. it's a new pdf object, which you're feeding an existing pdf into. that's how you get at the pdf metadata.

Comment: So to query an existing object, you have to create another one? Wow.
OK, so why does the function call the method "getNumberOfPages()"? Where does that come from in Apple's documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the only place you can find these terms is inside:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/CoreGraphics/**init**.py

This file lists all the method names used by python, and what the OS X reference name is.
The trouble is that the python list is old, and some of the methods have since been deprecated.